# I need to copy 3 columns from a huge csv file into a new csv file. How to do that?

Tags: ruby, csv, export-to-csv

I am very new to ruby. This is my code:

```
require 'csv'

csv = CSV.read('C:\Users\hp1\Desktop\Datasets\000.csv', :headers=>true)

p csv['timestamp']
f = File.new('C:\Users\hp1\Desktop\Datasets\Columns_000.csv', 'wb')
    f.puts(p)
    f.close
```

What I want to do in this code is, I want to read the 000.csv file, and copy the column named "timestamp" into another csv, Columns_000.csv.

But what happens is, it writes the timestamp column's values on my terminal. Instead, I want it to write them on the new csv.

And I have 2 more columns like that which I want to copy to the new csv. Is there a way to copy them all together, or will I need to copy them one by one?

Answer (score 2):

```
COLUMNS = ['timestamp', 'other1', 'other2']

# open new csv for writing
CSV.open("C:\Users\hp1\Desktop\Datasets\000_out.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  # iterating existing csv rows
  CSV.foreach('C:\Users\hp1\Desktop\Datasets\000.csv', :headers=>true) do |row|
    # select only those specified above columns
    csv << COLUMNS.map { |col| row[col] }
  end
end
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! It works!

But can you help me understand it? Like, what's "<<"? Isn't it supposed to be the bitwise left shift operator?

And what does "map" do exactly?

Comment: There is a great teacher that is always ready to help you to understand any code; her name is Ruby documentation: [`Array#<<`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C); [`Array#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-map). [`CSV`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) BTW.

Comment: Haha. Yeah, I went here before asking, multiple times, you know. But she does not explain well. For example, she mentions, "# use row here..."; but how exactly should the row be used here, that she does not say. Anyway, thanks a ton :)